# How to auto-scroll a webpage as elements are added above?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox

I am often on a webpage, and am about to click a link when the page simultaneously adds an element that it had been waiting to asynchronously receive from the server.  The element that I was about to click suddenly lurches downward, and I click on an entirely different element that sends me who-knows-where.  This happens with an incredible frequency, and the general behavior causes me frustration in other browser-based apps (such as with jupyter notebook).

I realize that since the page may add items anywhere, including in the middle of what I'm currently viewing, it is impossible to ensure a perfectly consistent view given the reality of dynamic websites.  However, even when items are added *outside of what I'm currently viewing*, what I'm currently viewing changes by being forced off-screen.  I would like to prevent this behavior by auto-scrolling the page to maintain a persistent viewport location for, e.g., the stuff at the bottom of my current viewport.

In any of the "big" browsers, (firefox, chrome, etc), is it possible to auto-scroll to maintain something like a consistent viewport during dynamic page updates?

Comment: I'm sure I read something recently about a browser that is working on this, but I can't find it. Sorry!